# Rails 7 - Undo/Remove a Schema.rb add_foreign_key reference & start over

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-7

I have started my project with a Users table and have since migrated to using an Accounts table. In the process I have an old reference to the Users table still in my schema.rb file and I need to remove it and create a new reference, or update the reference.

I am trying to work out a migration that will allow me to do this, however it keeps throwing an error as there's no Users table and when it did exist, it never had an account_id , which you can see referenced in my schema.rb file.

I really just need my schema.rb file to update
"add_foreign_key "likes", "users", column: "account_id"

to

add_foreign_key "likes", "accounts", column: "account_id"

But am finding this impossible to do with a migration without generating an error.

Any suggestions?

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 2022_01_18_013836) do

  create_table "accounts", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "email", default: "", null: false
    t.string "encrypted_password", default: "", null: false
    t.string "reset_password_token"
    t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at", precision: 6
    t.datetime "remember_created_at", precision: 6
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.string "username"
    t.string "first_name"
    t.string "last_name"
    t.index ["email"], name: "index_accounts_on_email", unique: true
    t.index ["reset_password_token"], name: "index_accounts_on_reset_password_token", unique: true
  end

  create_table "likes", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer "account_id", null: false
    t.integer "product_id", null: false
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.index ["account_id"], name: "index_likes_on_account_id"
    t.index ["product_id"], name: "index_likes_on_product_id"
  end

  create_table "products", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "product_name"
    t.string "product_category"
    t.string "product_type"
    t.string "product_image"
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.text "product_description"
    t.string "product_country"
  end

  add_foreign_key "likes", "products"
  add_foreign_key "likes", "users", column: "account_id"
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Best way to resolve this is to create a migration that adds users back with only account_id then remove the foreign key, and drop the user table again.
Should be doable in 1 migration, however I went about it as follows.

I ended up creating a new Users table with just an account_id:integer
Created a migration to remove_foreign_key
Then created a migration to then drop that Users table again.

Schema file is looking correct now and I have all the migrations to trace my changes.